# Restrict Access to Magento Admin Area in Nginx by IP

Tags: magento

I am trying to restrict access to admin area of magento in nginx. We use to do following in apache but don't know how to do it in Nginx:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^116\.71\.8\.191    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [F,L]
```

Regards,

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location /admin {
  allow   116.71.8.191;
  # drop rest of the world
  deny    all;
}
```

And don't forget reload rules

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

More info can be found here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/

Comment: So the problem was that it was not restricted with https. Can you tell me how can I restrict it for SSL as well

Comment: It should work both for http and https. Could you your full config for `/admin` location? Is `fastcgi_param HTTPS on;` present there?

Comment: It appears that HttpAccessModule is missing. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 with Varnish scheme

```
location ~* ^/(index\.php/admin|admin) {

allow 1.2.3.4;

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
location ~* \.php$ { try_files /dummy @proxy; }
deny all;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just add at

```
Location / {

if ($remote_addr !~ "^116.71.8.191"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($uri ~* "admin"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    return 403;
    break;
}
```